# How does Balancer work compared to Uniswap?

Tags: uniswap, balancer

Uniswap is for trading tokens, but what is Balancer use case? And what other competing platforms are there that does what Balancer does?

Comment: balancer v2 is better than uniswap v3. With uniswap v3 (compared to uniswap v2) your risk of losing increased 4000 times, while with balancer it is still the original mathematics on a curve without fancy tricks to use margin

Comment: also balancer v2 includes lending